# Target HTML element if attribute equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `HTML` template string that `prepends` some user info to a `div` for each user from an `Ajax` call. Each `div` has a `data-stream` attribute with either `false` or `true` values.

I want to target the `element` using `JS` or `jQuery` and use `CSS` or `addClass` on it if the `value` is true.

Maybe display a green icon if the value is true and a red one if false.

**JS**

---

```
var target = $('#result')

target.prepend('<div data-stream="' + userObj.stream + '" class="item "> <a target="_blank" href="' + userObj.url + '"> <img class="logo" src="' + userObj.logo + '"/> <span class="name">' + userObj.name + '</span> </a> </div>')
```

**My attempts**

```
  if ( typeof $(".item").attr('data-stream') === "true" ) {
            // style div here..
          }
```

that doesn't work, nor does:

```
 $('.item').filter(function(){
               var $this = $(this)
               return $this.data('data-stream') === true
            }).addClass('online')
```

nor:

```
 $("#results .item").find("[data-stream='true']")
```

There has got to be a pretty simple way to do this, any suggestions using jQuery or JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$("#results .item").find("[data-stream='true']")` was *really close*, but it looks for items with that attribute as *descendants* of the `.item` elements. You want to look for `.item` elements that *themselves* have that attribute and value:

```
$("#results .item[data-stream='true']")
```

Note no space between `.item` and `[data-stream='true']`. It's a *compound* selector.

Or **if** you have reason to do them separately as with your `find`, use `filter` rather than `find` (but only if you have a reason to separate the two aspects):

```
// If you have reason to separate the two aspects
$("#results .item").filter("[data-stream='true']")
```

Live Example of the compound selector:

```js
var target = $('#result')

target.prepend('<div data-stream="true" class="item ">This is the true one</div>');
target.prepend('<div data-stream="false" class="item ">This is the false one</div>');

console.log("Turning the true one blue with a class");
$("#result .item[data-stream='true']").addClass("foo");
```

```css
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Part of your question uses the `id` `result`, and other parts use `results`. You'll want those to match.

Comment: You're right, I mis-typed `results`, it should have been `result`. Your example was a really nice touch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use only CSS, targeting data-stream attribute's value:

**UPDATE:** Use :before to place an icon depending on the the data attribute

```css
.item:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: inherit;
   margin-right:5px;
}
.item[data-stream="true"]:before {
   content: "\f00c";
   color: green;       
 } 
.item[data-stream="false"]:before {
   content: "\f00d";
   color:red;
 }
```

```html
<div data-stream="true" class="item ">True</div>
<div data-stream="false" class="item ">False</div>
<div data-stream="true" class="item ">True</div>
<div data-stream="true" class="item ">True</div>
<div data-stream="false" class="item ">False</div>
<div data-stream="false" class="item ">False</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

When you want Javascript to Manipulate unique DOM elements you should always use IDs on those elements in order to be easily accessible.

Change your code to something like this :

```
target.prepend('<div id="YOUR_INIQUE_ID" data-stream="' + userObj.stream + '" class="item "> <a target="_blank" href="' + userObj.url + '"> <img class="logo" src="' + userObj.logo + '"/> <span class="name">' + userObj.name + '</span> </a> </div>')
```

and Access the element later using those IDs :

```
jQuery('#YOUR_INIQUE_ID').css('display','none');
```

**Addition :**

Checking your question again , i noticed that you are not after **Unique** document elements (or want to manipulate a very specific one) but after a **group** of elements. My first answer is not suited for your case.

**T.J. Crowder** proposal is suited for your case.

Comment: If jQuery was only meant to work on element IDs, it wouldn't support selecting elements in all sorts of other ways.

Comment: I mistakenly took his request as wanting to access unique elements in a Document thus i proposed the use of IDs. I don't get your jQuery reference , nevertheless , not everyone uses jQuery in their projects and accessing elements without the use of IDs in Javascript is not so "straight forward" as it is with them.