# Python Selenium Find if Element with an Attribute Equal to a Certain Value Exists in a Page

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python and Selenium to scrape a web page.

I am trying to find the following 'next page' button in the page:

```
<button class="pagination__next" aria-label="click to go to the next page" disabled="true" aria-hidden="true"></button>
```

`disabled='true'` appears when I'm on the last page of a multi-page embedded javascript generated table.

There may be more buttons on the page and some are disabled at the time I'm looking for this particular button.

So what I'm trying to do is determine if this particular button which has `class="pagination__next"` with attribute `disabled` equals `'true'` is in `driver.page_source`

There are plenty of examples around about identifying the particular tag ('button').  But not how to find the button *and* the button attribute `disabled` equal to `'true'`

I tried various approaches.  I think the closes I got was:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_name('pagination__next[disabled='true'])
```

but I don't think it worked.

There is an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520633/target-html-element-if-attribute-equals-a-certain-value) but OP asks for Java solution.  I'm looking for Python.

Guidance please.

Answer (score 1):

[`find_element_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) with multiple attributes is what you need, i.e.:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*/button[@class="pagination__next"][@disabled="true"]')`

Comment: Is this the only way? I (mis?)read elsewhere that xpath was not the ideal way to locate an element.  In addition, if the site owner changes the page structure won't xpath blow up?

Comment: No it's not the only way, you can select all buttons, then filter by `css` and lastly by `disabled` attribute, but `xpath` can be very efficient and precise locating elements, I guess it depends on how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.find_element_by_xpath` with the `AND` expression:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="pagination__next" and @disabled="true"]')
```

With the `AND` expression you can locate element with more than one condition using the attribute value.

[xpath-selenium OR & AND expression](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#7)